# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SOLDOUT')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to fetch data without using setTimeout from getProducts function. The code fetches data once in 50 trials when I tried setTimeout function outside the useEffect. I am new to react and I am trying to refactor the code.

```
const Allproducts = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
  let getProductsData = setTimeout(() => props.getProducts(), 10);
        return() => {
    clearTimeout(getProductsData);
  };
 },[]);

    const { data } = props.security;
let productsData=[];
    if(productsData['SOLDOUT'] === "" || productsData['AVAILABLE'] === "") {
      productsData= <Loader />;
    }

  return(
    <div>
      <div>
        <h1 className="primary-header">Products</h1>
        <Broadcast/>
      </div>
            
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Jumbotron id="allcards">
            <div className="card">
              <h2>{productsData['AVAILABLE']}</h2>
              <h6>Available</h6>
            </div>
          </Jumbotron>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Jumbotron id="allcards">
            <div className="card">
              <h2>{productsData['SOLDOUT']}</h2>
              <h6>Sold out</h6>
            </div>
          </Jumbotron>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  security: state.security,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts })(AllProducts);
```

Comment: Can you post your getProducts function ?

Comment: If you set `productsData` to an empty array right before trying to access `productsData['SOLDOUT']`, how would that value ever exist?

Comment: export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/all/products`);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PRODUCTS,
        payload: response.data,
      });
}; @SARANSURYA

Comment: I did it for the time being until I fetch the actual data from getProducts @DBS

Comment: You will have to perform async the fetch operations inside a async function and make sure you wait for the promise to resolve, Maybe that is the issue you are facing, because fetching data from a url will  have a small delay. Kindly try using async functions to handle fetch operations.

Comment: As I can see you assign `Loader` to `productsData` if `SOLDOUT` or `AVAILABLE` is empty , but you have not used `productsData` anywhere in return statement, so not getting what you are trying to do with productsData ?

Comment: I tried async await in useEffect. I just added an if else alert to see if the function is being called ``` export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/all/products`);
      if(response.status === 200){
        alert('success')
      }
      else{
        alert('Something is not working')
      }
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PRODUCTS,
        payload: response.data,
      });
}; but neither of the two alerts show up nor the data in the console. @SARANSURYA

Comment: The main issue here is the getProducts() is not being called, I am unable get data in console nor GET_PRODUCTS in redux dev tools but when I put it outside the useEffect and inside a setTimeout it simultaneously keeps giving me alert and data @sodhankit